# Why does `exit &` not work?

Tags: shell, exit

I don't understand why `exit &` does not work. Why does it not?

Comment: dummy question. I'd vote for closing it.

Comment: But people may not find the truth on demand then :(

Comment: Dummy truth isn't worth finding, don't worry ;)

Comment: But I am happy I found it, life fulfilled suddenly. :)

Comment: Same reason `cd / &` "doesn't work"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think it works.
But probably it doesn't do what you expect.

```
 $ exit &
```

Will create a sub-shell process, and make it run as a background job which will just finish right away.

Comment: In other words, this is the "fake your own death" operator.

Answer (score 17):

It does work.  `&` forks the shell, starting a new process (you could think of it as `& exit`, except of course that syntax actually means something else). `exit` is a shell built-in that ends the shell process -- in this case the new backgrounded shell.

```
> exit &
[1] 1709
> ps -p 1709
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
[1]+  Done                    exit
```

There's your job.  It's done.  It worked.